# Suppose that we have $n$ people (where $n \geq 4$) to be seated around a circular dinner table with $n$ seats labeled $1, \ldots, n$ .

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> Four of the guests are Alice, Bob, Chad, and Diane. Find the number of valid settings if Alice and Bob must be seated together. Chad and Diane must be seated together. Note: Alice/Bob need not be seated next to Chad/Diane.

I am solving this problem that is from the book "How to Count: An Introduction to Combinatorics and Its Applications" Exercise 2.3.12.
I have tried to solve it manually for $n=4$.

There are $24$ permutations of ABCD. Only $16$ ways that Alice and Bob are next to each other, and Chad and Diane are next to each other. However, when I tried to compare when Alice and Chad must not be next to each other and Bob and Diane are not next to each other, I only got $8$ permutations. Am I on the right track? What possible theorems can I use to show that Alice/Bob need not be seated next to Chad/Diane?

Comment: I am confused with the note that Alice/Bob need not be seated next to Chad/Diane.

Comment: The number of ways for Alice and Bob to be seated together is 2n(n!). Similarly, the number of ways for Chad and Diane to be seated together is 2n(n!).

Comment: Can you show me the solution to how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try placing Alice and Bob first, then place Chad and Diane in the remaining seats.

Comment: Is this the text by Robert A. Beeler?

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted an answer, received help indicating that my answer was wrong, and revised my answer.  Then, I received more help, indicating that my answer was still wrong.  Therefore, I deleted my answer.  After reading N.F.Taussig's answer, I thought about it privately, and came to the same computation that he did.

Answer (score 1):

Since the seats are numbered, there are $n$ ways to seat Alice.  Since Bob must be seated next to Alice, there are $2$ ways to seat Bob.  That leaves $n - 2$ seats, which are consecutive since Alice and Bob sit in adjacent seats.  As we proceed clockwise from the pair of seats occupied by Alice and Bob, the pair of adjacent seats occupied by Chad and Diane must begin in one of the first $n - 2 - 1 = n - 3$ of those $n - 2$ seats.  There are $2$ ways to pick whether Chad or Diane sits in the selected seat with the smaller number.  The other must occupy the other selected seat.  That leaves $n - 4$ seats for the remaining $n - 4$ people.  They can be seated in those seats in $(n - 4)!$ ways.  Hence, the number of seating arrangements for the $n$ people in the $n$ seats at the circular table in which Alice sits next to Bob and Chad sits next to Diane is
$$2n \cdot 2(n - 3)(n - 4)! = 4n(n - 3)!$$

Comment: +1 : nice analysis.  After re-considering, I came to the same conclusion that you did.  I deleted my answer.

Comment: If n=4, then by using the formula, we will have 16 seating arrangements for the restriction. However, if there is no restriction, isn't it that we only have 6 permutations since (4-1)!=6. Are we not considering the fact that the table is circular and apply the formula (n-1)!?

Comment: @mburbs I am confused as to what you are asking here.  If you set $n = 4$, then you have $4$ choices for the Alice::Bob combination: $(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,1)$.  For these $4$ choices, Alice::Bob can be in either order.  Then, once Alice::Bob are set, there are $2$ choices for the Chad::Diane seating.  So, the computation, when $n=4$ is in fact $(4 \times 2 \times 2)$, which is consistent with the formula given in this answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have manually tried to list the arrangements (when n=4) to check it.